# streaming from rackspace using flowplayer

Tags: javascript, flowplayer, rackspace-cloud

I have this code to stream from AWS

```
        $f('.rtmp', 'http://dmjae0nvian3n.cloudfront.net/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf', {
            clip: {
                provider: 'rtmp'
            },

            plugins: {
                rtmp: {
                    url: '@Url.Content("~/Content/swf/AkamaiFlowPlugin.swf")',

                    netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://sh6xkdarh1a51.cloudfront.net/cfx/st'
                }
            }
        });
```

HTML

```
<div class="rtmp" href="mp4:Delicious_Vinyl"/>
```

This works fine. Now I am trying to do the same file from rackspace. All I am doing is changing the netConnectionUrl. The file name is the same in both.

RackSpace Url

```
8abb0c8bf43b4e6ae1d1-1bec6be0e9b91559fcee217d2d0b0f03.r99.stream.cf1.rackcdn.com
```

**EDIT**

I get a 403 forbidden error

Answer (score 0):

Here is the javascript code. I am still hosting the swk file on AWS I was getting domain errors when I tried to have it local

```
var jp = $f
        (
            "player_container",

            {
                src: "http://dmjae0nvian3n.cloudfront.net/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf",
                wmode: 'transparent'
            },
            {
                debug: true,
                log: 'warn',
                clip:
                {
                    live: false,
                    provider: 'akamai',
                    autoPlay: false,
                    stopLiveOnPause: false
                },
                playlist:
                [
                    'http://8abb0c8bf43b4e6ae1d1-1bec6be0e9b91559fcee217d2d0b0f03.r99.stream.cf1.rackcdn.com/Delicious_Vinyl.mp4'
                ],
                plugins:
                {
                    //controls: controlObject,
                    akamai:
                    {
                        url: 'http://players.edgesuite.net/flash/plugins/flow/v3.1.1/AkamaiFlowPlugin.swf'
                    }
                }
            }
        );
```